# How to specify a non global from name when sending mail in laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-mail

I'm using laravel 7.x with mailgun running on my local environment and everything seems to be running fine.  I want to be able to set the from "name" when sending individual emails.

In Laravel 7.x documentation on "[Configuring The Sender](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#configuring-the-sender)" they explain how to send an email and specify a "from address", but do not show how to set a name.

```
return $this->from('example@example.com')
            ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
```

They also specify how to set a global from address with the name set

```
'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

I want to be able to **send an email where I can set multiple names** depending on which part of the application I'm sending from.  (e.g. password reset would be different from a usage notification)

## What **does not** work

The example below returns `Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [Test User <example@example.com>] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2`

```
return $this->from('Test User <example@example.com>')
            ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
```

I also tried using the array syntax from the global method, but this didn't seem to have any impact on the name itself.

```
return $this->from([
    'address' => 'example@example.com',
    'name' => 'Test User'
])
->view('emails.orders.shipped');
```

Is it possible to set the name using this method?

Comment: Does `$this->from('example@example.com','Example')->view('emails.orders.shipped');` work?

Comment: @user3647971 it does!  mark as an answer and I'll accept, thanks!

Comment: Also I checked the RFC compliance exception and that particular section of the RFC standard describes _how_ **from** **sender** and **reply_to** fields should be populated and in what situations. Doesn't describe the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this syntax:

```
$this->from('example@example.com','Example')->view('emails.orders.shipped');
```

I could not find the proper documentation for this, but similar syntax was used in laravel emails.